# Reshape Dataframe with Non-Unique Index in Python 2.7 and Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
             Weight              Ticker
Date                                    
2002-12-31  0.005953              PWER
2002-12-31  0.010682               TUP
2002-12-31  0.012403             AAMRQ
2003-01-31  0.012960               GTW
2003-01-31  0.023259          2987536Q
```

I want to get it into the following form:

```
                   PWER      TUP      AAMRQ     GTW    2987536Q
Date
2002-12-31      0.005953   0.010682  0.012403    Nan     Nan
2003-01-31         Nan        Nan       Nan   0.012960 0.023259
```

I can't reshape using pivot (and resetting the index) because the date values are not unique.  The only way I can think of accomplishing this is through brute force iteration.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to handle it for non-unique values? You can use pivot_table to aggregate (take the first one, last one, or the mean, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reset the index to make the `Date`s a column, then you can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
In [25]: df.reset_index().pivot(index='Date', columns='Ticker', values='Weight')
Out[25]: 
Ticker      2987536Q     AAMRQ      GTW      PWER       TUP
Date                                                       
2002-12-31       NaN  0.012403      NaN  0.005953  0.010682
2003-01-31  0.023259       NaN  0.01296       NaN       NaN
```

Note that if there are no duplicate `(Date, Ticker)` pairs, then you can use `pivot`. If there are duplicates, (as [ayhan suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600411/reshape-dataframe-with-non-unique-index-in-python-2-7-and-pandas/42600465#comment72331611_42600411)) you'll need to use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) and specify an `aggfunc` -- a function that aggregates the multiple values associated with the duplicate `(Date, Ticker)` pair into an single value.

Comment: Ugh!  I should ding myself on this one!  I actually did this on two lines but didn't set the dataframe equal to the dataframe with the reset index (e.g. `df.reset_index()` instead of `df = df.reset_index()`.  So I was getting a key error when I ran `df.pivot(...)` on the next line.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, it's so important to keep track of which functions return a value (like `df.reset_index`) vs modifying the caller in-place (like `df.update`). Impossible to tell without remembering or reading docstrings...